# Modify the structure of data returned by $wpdb

Tags: wpdb, sql

Modify the structure of multidimensional array outputed by SQL via $wpdb

The output that I need from `$wpdb` is easily achievable by running multiple queries within `foreach`. However, I am trying to avoid the same for performance issues.

I have two custom tables:

```
items
- item_id
- item_name

sub_items
- sub_item_id
- item_id
- sub_item_name
```

The query I am running:

```
$items_tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'items';
$sub_items_tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'sub_items';
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * from $sub_items_tbl LEFT JOIN $items_tbl ON $items_tbl.item_id = $sub_items_tbl.item_id"), ARRAY_A);
```

This is the resultant output of the above query:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        ['sub_item_id'] => 1
        ['item_id'] => 1
        ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum'
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
    )
    [1] => array(
        ['sub_item_id'] => 2
        ['item_id'] => 1
        ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Ornare Parturient'
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
    )
    [2] => array(
        ['sub_item_id'] => 3
        ['item_id'] => 2
        ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Adipiscing Malesuada'
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
    )
    [3] => array(
        ['sub_item_id'] => 4
        ['item_id'] => 2
        ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Ligula'
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
    )
    [4] => array(
        ['sub_item_id'] => 5
        ['item_id'] => 2
        ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Sit Adipiscing'
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
    )
)
```

And this is the output I need:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        ['item_id'] => 1
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
        ['sub_items'] =>[0] => array(
                            ['sub_item_id'] => 1
                            ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum'
                        )
                        [1] => array(
                            ['sub_item_id'] => 2
                            ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Ornare Parturient'
                        )
    )
    [1] => array(
        ['item_id'] => 2
        ['item_name'] => Some Item Name
        ['sub_items'] =>[0] => array(
                            ['sub_item_id'] => 3
                            ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Adipiscing Malesuada'
                        )
                        [1] => array(
                            ['sub_item_id'] => 4
                            ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Ligula'
                        )
                        [2] => array(
                            ['sub_item_id'] => 5
                            ['sub_item_name'] => 'Lorem Ipsum Sit Adipiscing'
                        )
    )
)
```

I'd preferably want to modify the sql to give me the resultant output. However, if that cannot be achieved then how can the output be altered in PHP?

Comment: `$wpdb->prepare()` behaves similar to `(s)printf()`. It's completely worthless if you don't use the `%s/%d` parts and place your vars directly in the string...

Comment: @kaiser Were you referring to the vars I used for the tables? Other than that query above makes use of no other vars and hence in the above case `$wpdb->prepare()` seems of no use, though I have a habit of using it every time to avoid forgetting it.

Comment: All your variables like `$sub_items_tbl` are _unknown_ to WordPress. WP can only check against default, builtin tables. Everything else has to be considered _unsafe_. That's why you should place `%s` for every custom table name, like `$sub_items_tbl`.

Comment: @kaiser Point noted. I do not include the vars for table names as these are hard coded and never populated via a user input. Thx.

Comment: Which doesn't mean that they are save. The `%s/%d` cares about converting those so you _only_ got strings or digits.

Comment: @kaiser Why wouldn't hard coded vars for table names be safe? Confuses me.

Comment: Because you don't always have full control (or could loose part of it without even knowing) over what happens until the actual query happens. Anyway, if you feel comfortable doing so, then simply do it. Not going to argue on that topic.

Comment: @kaiser I get your point. BTW, no arguments — It's always better to know the reason, understand it, and have your bases clear. Thx for the insight.

Comment: @kaiser Thought of sharing this info after trying to follow your recommendation of including table name vars in `$wpdb->prepare()`. Pls see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25850/9094

Comment: "sharing this info"? Sry, but I couldn't find your name on the other, quite old, question. What are you talking about?

Comment: @kaiser Well, after trying to follow your recommendation I bumped into the exact problem that's described in the link I posted above. It appears that table name vars cannot be used in  `$wpdb->prepare()`. Any comments you'd have on it or a solution that makes table name vars work with `$wpdb->prepare()`? I hope I am able to make myself clear. Pls note that I am just trying to understand and implement your suggestion and that I am not into some sort of a debate.

Comment: I commented [there](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35710/385) that adding to the `$wpdb` object is not recommended. Or are you talking about surrounding single quotes or what? Because in this case your inserted string would look like `wp_'items'`, which is nonsense and **should** break :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways, as far as I can see:

1. Use PHP to combine the current results to the one you want.  Basically:

   $records = array();

   ```
   foreach( $results as $result )
   {
       $record_id = $result['item_id'];
       if (empty($records[$record_id])) {
           $records[$record_id]['item_id'] = $result['item_id'];
           $records[$record_id]['item_name'] = $result['item_name'];
           $records[$record_id]['sub_items'] = array();
       }
       $records[$record_id]['sub_items'][] = array( 
          'sub_item_id' => $result['sub_item_id'],
          'sub_item_name' => $result['sub_item_name']  
       );
   }
   ```
2. Other way is doing 2 queries.  first one finds the main items.  One you have the item ids of the main items, you do a secondary query where you get all the sub-items whose item_id is in the ones you queries before.  Then, you use PHP to put it together in nested arrays, similar to the first option.

As far as I can tell, you can't really do nested results in mySQL like you want, so you'll have to do the legwork in PHP.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. The PHP solution works as intended. Your second solution would be a performance tax since queries would need to be run inside of a `foreach` loop — The very reason I asked this question in the first place. Again thx for the solution.

Comment: Well, technically the second option only needs 2 queries. Also I made a correction in the answer.  I suggest you use the new answer.